# Genexus shows IIS error

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to setup Genexus in IIS but after running the web.config setting tool and copying the file I get the following error, any ideas?
thanks!

Detailed Error Information:

```
Module
   ConfigurationValidationModule 

Notification
   BeginRequest 

Handler
   StaticFile 

Error Code
   0x80070032 


Requested URL
   http://localhost:80/PurchasesM 

Physical Path
   E:\Data\Projects\models\pur\web 

Logon Method
   Not yet determined 

Logon User
   Not yet determined
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you're using an application pool (ASP.NET version) which is not compatible with NET Framework version used to compile the application.
(e.g. the application was compiled using NET Framework 2.0 and Virtual directory uses Framework 4.0)

Please, check what application pool are you using in the IIS (app virtual directory). Using IIS Manager/Your_Virtual_Directory/Advanced Settings/Application pool.

Changing it the application should work.

Comment: thanks for the response, I changed the app pool settings to managed pipeline=classic Now I get the following error
Line 1:  <configuration>
Line 2:    <configSections>
Line 3:      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert, learning GeneXus for last five months. 
Recently I also faced this kind of problem. I think it version problem of **.net**.

I managed to overcome this. I think you should turn on **"IIS"** from **"program and feature"**,  then [select this check box option shown in attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxgVR.png)
[select this check box option shown in attached image][2]

Then you need to confirm that **.NET framework 4.5** is reside/already installed in your PC. If the problem still on, then please download .NET 4.5 following this link "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653". 
It may require install/ repair. whatever it is after doing restart you PC.

I managed to fix this following this process. I don't know will it work for you or not, but hope it will and help you to fix the problem.